# All External Assets Sources Display on MSM Site

Tags: assets, multi-site-manager, s3

I have several S3 external sources set up with Assets on an MSM site. Some sources are for Site 1 and some are for Site 2. However, when I go to the Assets file manager on Site 2, the external sources for Site 1 display also. Same for vice-versa.

- EE 2.7.2
- Assets 2.2.2

Comment: Hi Kristen, did you resolve this in the end?

Comment: Hi Rob, nope. As far as I can tell, Assets external sources don't recognize MSM.